# Windows 8: Changing default numlock state to 0 doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-8, regedit, numlock

After logging in to Windows 8, the numlock is on. I have a notebook, so this is bad, I have no numbers block.

With this howto, I tried to deactivate this:
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Numlock-State

but after restarting the value is "2" again. Even if I make the change as "admin", it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does your bios have a numlock power on option? if so it is likely overriding the registery setting.

Comment: hi, no I found nothing in BIOS related to this issue. there must be an app or program which is overwriteing the value on startup ...